# QGraphicsWidget's mouse drag.

Tags: c++, qt

How to implement mouse draging on QGraphicsWidget?

I tried with

```
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
```

And that works sometime (?)

[image]

For example, node 6 I can move with mouse, but rest of nodes wont move.

Also, how can I implement that when I move some node, edge that attached to that node move with it.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason may be that you have not provided an override of the `shape()` function. This function is used to define the "collision" geometry: the parts of the object that you can click on. If you inherrit from `QGraphicsItem` directly, it all seems to work fine without providing a definition, but `QGraphicsWidget` overrides the `shape()` function itself and simply returns `QWidget::rect()` (which may also not be defined in your class), so the default implementation from `QGraphicsItem` isn't being used anymore when you inherit from `QGraphicsWidget`!

If you provide a definition of the shape function that returns an ellipse that surrounds the circle you draw for your node, I bet it just might start working. For example:

```
QPainterPath MyGraphicsWidget::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addEllipse(QPointF(0, 0), 25, 25);
    return path;
}
```

This may be an old question, but I just spent 3 hours trying to figure this out, myself. Hopefully this answer is useful to someone out there if not you ;)

Answer (score 0):

setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable) should be all you need to make a QGraphicsItem draggable with the mouse; you might want to check your code to see if you are accidentally un-setting that flag somewhere on the other objects, or something like that.  (Also if you are subclassing from QGraphicsItem directly and not from one of the provided subclasses like QGraphicsEllipseItem, make sure your contains() and boundingRect() methods are returning the correct results)

As for making the attached edge move with the node, I think you'll need to do that in your own code.  In particular, call setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges) on any nodes that have one or more edge objects associated with them.  Then in your QGraphicsItem subclass that implements the node, override the `QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange, const QVariant &)` method.  In your implementation of that method, watch for when the first argument's value is equal to QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged, and if it is, update any associated edge objects so that the appropriate endpoint is moved to the node's new position.

Comment: But its not QGraphicsItem, its QGraphicsWidget. When I subclass QGraphicsItem, all works, but problem is that I need to animate my scene, and need for that QGraphicsWidgets, because they have propertieswhich I can animate with QPropertyAnimation

Comment: Hmm.  Does your QGraphicsWidget subclass override mousePressEvent() or mouseMoveEvent() or anything like that?  If so, you might examine those reimplementations and see what effect they are having on the mouse-event processing (e.g. do they only call up to the superclass in certain cases?  Do they call e->accept() or e->ignore() only in certain cases?)  If so, that might explain why dragging only works in certain cases.

Comment: It does. I reimplement mousePressEvent to popup menu on right click. But I tried without reimplementing there is still problem. However when I have node without edges it work fine, but with edge it wont work. Edges are another object that inherits QGraphicsWIdget, and it draws indepedent of node (first i draw edges, then nodes).

Comment: Perhaps the edge objects are "stealing" the mouse events away from the node objects?  Try using setZValue() to place the edge objects behind the node objects and see if that makes the mouse handling work better.  You might also consider subclassing the edge objects from QGraphicsLineItem (if possible) rather than QGraphicsWidget.